# using commandline to verify that a Deployment Type has a Global Condition

Tags: powershell-3.0, wmi-query, sccm

Currently scripting for SCCM to automate

- creation of collections
- populating collections
- etc..

I'd like to add a "verification" step.

I want to ensure (through commandline since I want to automate it) that a Deployment Type has at least one Global Condition.

I searched

- a commandlet : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821831%28v=sc.20%29.aspx

Could I find a commandlet that would do the trick ?

- a way using WMI : `Get-WmiObject -list -Namespace root\sms\site_[sitecode]`

Could i find a class that would give me the information ?

- a WQL

I found two information :

- whether a Global Condition is in use or not : interesting but not quite useful in my case
- the Global Condition name(s) can be found using `Get-CMDeploymentType -applicationname [AppName]).SDMPackageXML`

My Global Conditions have not all the same prefix. So the following might work in some case but can not be trusted : `PS P41:\> (Get-CMDeploymentType -applicationname PKG_10).SDMPackageXML -match "GC_"`

That is where I need a little help. What am I missing ? Which WQL query would give me the information/confirmation I need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution !
I kept digging in the TechNet and found two things :

- how to deserialize
- my choice of words was bad : when speaking about Deployment Types, we do speak no more about Global Conditions but about Requirements

In the end, I solved my need with the following :
`([Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer]::DeserializeFromString((Get-CMApplication -name AppName).SDMPackageXML)).DeploymentTypes.Requirements.Count`

Of course, if there are more than one Deployment Types,
`([Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer]::DeserializeFromString((Get-CMApplication -name winzip_FR_1.5.0_R1.000).SDMPackageXML)).DeploymentTypes[n].Requirements.Count`

Well, thanks,